# PHP static code analysis tool that follows includes (framework compatible)

Tags: php, static-analysis

I have been looking for a PHP taint analysis tool, or a PHP parser that can include files within its analysis.

For example:

```
include "asdf.php"

//this is a function defined in asdf.php
echo test($_GET["test"]);
```

The tool should include asdf.php into the analysis. Has anyone seen such a tool, or is this just a big gap?

So far, the best parser I have seen is https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser , which I have considered writing something to do the above. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking only for free tools or paid ones are also possible?

Comment: Free tools would be better as it is for research.